# Turning 'What value of T is just small enough to make the bulb light?' into its affirmative form

Tags: grammaticality, questions

I am somehow confused with regard to the way the following question is constructed

> What value of T is just small enough to make the bulb light?

The question below, in contrast, is clear and we can see how it was formed starting from its 'original' form.

> What *is the* value of T *that* is just small enough to make the bulb light?

*First*: The affirmative form

> The value of T that is just small enough to make the bulb light is (What).

*Second*: Bringing the wh-word to the front

> (What) The value of T that is just small enough to make the bulb light is.

*Finally*: Subject-verb inversion

> What is The value of T that is just small enough to make the bulb light?

I cannot apply the same procedure to first question to see how it was obtained; is it even grammatical?

Comment: "to make the bulb light" is awkward: to light the bulb.

Comment: The first example you give is grammatical, and reasonably common usage. Not sure I understand what YOU are asking though!

Comment: I am trying to obtain the affirmative form from which the first question was derived, similar to the form I wrote in the first step of the procedure.

Comment: Your "affirmative form" is a different statement (though semantically related): the "What" in parenthesis is functioning as a noun phrase. But "What" in the original question is functioning as an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While one can think of a question as being derived from a statement, a native sp3aker does not typically first construct a statement and then transform it into a question.  Similarly, while a question like your original example:

> What value of T is just small enough to make the bulb light?

can be thought of as being an elided form, constructions of the general form

> What X is Y

or

> What value of X is enough to Y

are grammatically valid as they stand.

Here "T" is some property that has a numerical value. If T is small enough, a bulb lights up. This obviously assumes some particular equipment, but that is not relevant to the grammer. The point is that T has a value, and the question is: "What value of T has {Effect Y}?" A parallel question might be

> What color traffic light causes drivers to stop?

(The answer, of course, is "Red".)

That question is fine as it stands, and does not need to be recast as:

> What color of traffic light **is it** **that** causes drivers to stop?

The basic pattern here is "What X is Y?", not "What X is it that is Y?"